# OpenGL Accumulation Buffer in SFML?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

How would I enable the glAccum buffer in SFML? It doesn't appear to exist by default (glGet(GL_ACCUM_BLUE_BIT) returns 0). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with SFML 1.6 or 2.0. And I wouldn't hold my breath on them adding such a feature anytime soon. They were [incredibly resistant to the simple suggestion of allowing sRGB framebuffers.](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/175)

I'd suggest switching to [Allegro 5](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/), as they provide accumulation buffer support.

Comment: Accumulation buffers are deprecated since 3.0 and removed in 3.1, so it's definitely the right thing to do for SFML to not provide them -- it'd just add even more cruft that they will have a hard time getting rid of later on. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435589/opengl-motion-blur-without-accumulation-buffer for alternatives